# How to read new entires from a file using Kafka

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

This is my Kafka code to read from a file:

```java
public void run() throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    prop.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    prop.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(prop);

    String currentLine = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        ProducerRecord<String, String>  message = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, currentLine);
        producer.send(message);
    }
    reader.close();
    producer.close();   
}
```

But this code only runs one which is obvious.
But I have a file which keeps on updating new lines every hour.
If I use above code this will run the entire file again.How can rerun only for new lines which is added to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should depend on how file is managed. If it can be rotated and you need to handle recovery, then Flume or tail -F (which is how Flume 1.6 is implemented anyway) will not work for you. Also, what OS are you using?
Another approach may be tail with logstash or file beats and write to Kafka. If you like python, take a look at tailcher (https://github.com/thanos/tailchaser)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try linux pipes **tail+[kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat)** instead of writing your own code.

"tail -F" will read new entries from the file, pipes to kafkacat and produce to 'syslog' topic with snappy compression

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog | kafkacat -b mybroker -t syslog -z snappy
```

Be careful to use -F instead of -f,   -F is able to handle **log rotation problem**.
-F keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessible; useful when following by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also very well make use of `Apache Flume` here along with `Kafka`.

Flume will stream data from a `file` to `Kafka Broker`.

Please have a look at `KafkaSink` which `Flume` provides.

Please have a look at Apache Flume docs below:

https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.6.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/kafka/KafkaSink.html